# ClickHouse init process failed. There is no projection XX in table

Tags: clickhouse

```
2022.01.26 11:28:41.502968 [ 108 ] {} <Error> `454959780851617792`.log_detail (9456207b-f9c8-4174-9456-207bf9c8b174): auto DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::processQueueEntry(ReplicatedMergeTreeQueue::SelectedEntryPtr)::(anonymous class)::operator()(DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::LogEntryPtr &) const: Code: 582, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: There is no projection log_trace_service_stat_projection in table, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0x8b6cbba in /usr/bin/clickhouse
1. DB::ProjectionsDescription::get(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const @ 0xfde09b1 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
2. DB::MutationsInterpreter::prepare(bool) @ 0xfaa64f6 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
3. DB::MutationsInterpreter::MutationsInterpreter(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage>, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::MutationCommands, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, bool) @ 0xfaa4f3c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
4. DB::MergeTreeDataMergerMutator::mutatePartToTemporaryPart(DB::FutureMergedMutatedPart const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::MutationCommands const&, DB::BackgroundProcessListEntry<DB::MergeListElement, DB::MergeInfo>&, long, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::Context>, std::__1::unique_ptr<DB::IReservation, std::__1::default_delete<DB::IReservation> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&) @ 0x1018c94b in /usr/bin/clickhouse
5. DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::tryExecutePartMutation(DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry const&) @ 0xfefd59d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
6. DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::executeLogEntry(DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry&) @ 0xfeec1c2 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
7. ? @ 0xff6f23f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
8. DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeQueue::processEntry(std::__1::function<std::__1::shared_ptr<zkutil::ZooKeeper> ()>, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry>&, std::__1::function<bool (std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeLogEntry>&)>) @ 0x102ef74c in /usr/bin/clickhouse
9. DB::StorageReplicatedMergeTree::processQueueEntry(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::ReplicatedMergeTreeQueue::SelectedEntry>) @ 0xff1efbd in /usr/bin/clickhouse
10. ? @ 0x100b52b7 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
11. ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0x8baf998 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
12. ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda1'()>(void&&, void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda1'()&&...)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0x8bb135f in /usr/bin/clickhouse
13. ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0x8bacedf in /usr/bin/clickhouse
14. ? @ 0x8bb0403 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
15. start_thread @ 0x9609 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
16. clone @ 0x122293 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
 (version 21.6.5.37 (official build))
ClickHouse init process failed.
```

I kill a clickhouse pod of two pod of a share.but the pod restart fail.

the projection log_trace_service_stat_projection is not exist in other clickhouse node.

I query system.projection_parts, but I am not find it.

Can someone help me to understand why the process init fail?

How to fix it? Thank you!!

Comment: 21.6 is out of support

Comment: upgrade clickhouse to 21.8